# When can you evaluate the components of an integral separately?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

The following question is given:

Under which assumption on the sequence $(c_n)$ can you evaluate the integral

$\int_0^\pi \sin(mx)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin(nx)\right)\,dx$

componentwise?

I am not sure I understand what is meant by componentwise in this context.
I assume it is meant when I can first evaluate the series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\sin(nx)$

and then integrate?

Most definitely the series should converge.
Maybe you need continuously convergence so you can interchange limit process, but I am not sure.

Can you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"evaluate componentwise" doesn't seem right; better would be "evaluate termwise". The question is(?) to determine when you can say the integral of the sum is the sum of the integrals: $$\int_0^\pi\sin(mx)\sum c_n\sin(nx)=(?)\sum c_n\int_0^\pi\sin(mx)\sin(nx).$$

There are presumably various conditions that would allow this, but the most basic, the one they're probably expecting, is that this works if the sum $\sum c_n\sin(mx)\sin(nx)$ converges uniformly; since $|\sin|\le1$ it follows from the M-test that this holds if $$\sum|c_n|<\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably that is the question, but it is not clearly formulated like this. The question is stated as I have in my original post, but I am almost certain that your interpretation is correct.